# NPM error TS2304: Cannot find name 'VRDisplay' for ThreeJS

Tags: node.js, npm

The errors are below.

```
ERROR in node_modules/@types/three/three-core.d.ts(7800,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'VRDisplay'.
node_modules/@types/three/three-core.d.ts(7801,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'VRDisplay'.
node_modules/@types/three/three-vrcontrols.d.ts(15,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'VRDisplay'.
node_modules/@types/three/three-vreffect.d.ts(20,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'VRDisplay'.
```

I've tried all sorts of changes to the tsconfig.json file and checking to make sure the npm installs were fine. Some minor versions differ with other servers that have the same package.json, but nothing that should break this.

Why might this issue be coming up?

Should note, we use node 6.12.10 and npm 3.10.10 because of reasons out of my power.

Comment: Same problem here. As workaround for this I edited files you mentioned and set type from `VRDisplay` to `any`.

Answer (score 2):

Actually `VRDisplay` is not a class of `three.js` but a web interface of the WebVR API. `npm install --save @types/webvr-api` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Belane's answer, I had to import the `weber-api` somewhere (before importing three?):

```
import { VRDisplay } from 'webvr-api';
```

EDIT: this worked in live reloading "ionic serve", but it blows up "ionic build"... Gave up and changed "VRDisplay" to "any" in @types/three.

Answer (score 1):

**Getting error?**

Cannot find name 'VRDisplay'.

It's just a typescript version. You need to update typescript version please find below command.
**npm install typescript@2.8.1**

Working fine without any errors.